# Can I assign a specific environment/docker image to my Kaggle notebook?

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I want to create a new Kaggle notebook that would be relying on the same environment than an older Kaggle notebook I have.
**Why ?**  Because I want to use the commit & save function allowing you to run stuff in the background, without having it running my entire original notebook as it would do a lot of unecessary compute for my test.

From my understanding, when you create a new Kaggle notebook it is assigned the most recent environment as of today. You can then choose to have it locked, or keep your environment evolving by staying on the latest available version.
However is it possible to assign **an older version** of the environment? Basically on the docker image I get today, the code I want to test is not running because of some library version conflicts. There are hundreds of libraries that have been updated within a month, so pinpointing the exact origin of the bug is extremely tidious. I already tried to rollback the libraries I suspected initially without success.
The solution I have now is basically commenting my whole notebook to just keep the cells I want to run for the test, but it is also not efficient.

Comment: Get the [release](https://github.com/Kaggle/docker-python/releases) of your choice from github and read the `README.md` on how to build.